# Setting up D3 in Angular Service, passing to Angular Link Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I am working with Angular and D3, moving everything from the link function to a service and then injecting the service into the custom directive and using it in the Link Function. I have the graph rendering but am getting some weird behavior in that if I 3 custom graph directives on the page like so:

```
<div ng-controller="example1 as ctrl">
  <diagram nodes="ctrl.filteredNodes" edges="ctrl.edges" height="500" direction="LR"></diagram>
</div>

<div ng-controller="example2 as ctrl">
  <diagram nodes="ctrl.filteredNodes" edges="ctrl.edges" height="500"    direction="LR"></diagram>
</div>

<div ng-controller="example3 as ctrl">
  <diagram nodes="ctrl.filteredNodes" edges="ctrl.edges" height="300" direction="TB"></diagram>
</div>
```

All three of the components take the direction of the third diagram above. If I were to remove the third one then I would get the graph to render correctly moving from left to right. Does anybody know what that would be doing so? Here is my service and link function?

```
 service("diagramService", ["$rootScope", function ($rootScope:ng.IScope) {
    var isUpdate = false;
    var roundNodeCorners = true;
    var direction;
    var g;
    var zoom;
    var originalZoomScale;

    // get the initial direction, if not specified set it as Top to Bottom
    this.getDirection = function (directionSelected:any) {
        if (directionSelected) {
            return direction = directionSelected;
        } else {
            return direction = "TB";
        }
    };

    // scale the graph. Runs once on page load and then each time the user specifies a zoom in or out
    this.scaleGraph = function(svg:any, useAnimation:any, autoResizeGraph:any, direction:any) {
        console.log(svg);
            var graphWidth = g.graph().width + 4;
            var graphHeight = g.graph().height + 4;
            var width = parseInt(svg.style("width").replace(/px/, ""), 10);
            var height = parseInt(svg.style("height").replace(/px/, ""), 10);
            var zoomScale = originalZoomScale;
            // Zoom and scale to fit
            if (autoResizeGraph === "disabled") {
                zoomScale = 1;
            } else {
                // always scale to canvas if set to fill or if auto (when larger than canvas)   
                if (autoResizeGraph === "fill" || (graphWidth > width || graphHeight > height)) {
                    zoomScale = Math.min(width / graphWidth, height / graphHeight);
                }
            }

            var translate; 

            if (direction.toUpperCase() === "TB") {
                // Center horizontal + align top (offset 1px)
                translate =  [(width / 2) - ((graphWidth * zoomScale) / 2) + 2, 1];
            } else if (direction.toUpperCase() === "LR") {
                // Center vertical (offset 1px)
                translate =  [1, (height / 2) - ((graphHeight * zoomScale) / 2)];
            } else {
                // Center horizontal and vertical
                translate = [(width / 2) - ((graphWidth * zoomScale) / 2), (height / 2) - ((graphHeight * zoomScale) / 2)];
            }

            zoom.center([width / 2, height / 2]);
            zoom.size([width, height]);

            zoom.translate(translate);
            zoom.scale(zoomScale);

            // If rendering the first time, then don't use animation
            zoom.event(useAnimation ? svg.transition().duration(500) : svg);
        };

        // render the graph on page load and each time something changes with the nodes or edges
        this.renderGraph = function(svgElement:any, currentNodes:any, currentEdges:any, enableMouseWheelZoom:any, selectedNode:any,
            selectedEdge:any, nodeSelectedCallback:any, edgeSelectedCallback:any, autoResizeGraph:any) {
                var nodes = currentNodes;
                var edges = currentEdges;
                var svg = svgElement;
                if (!nodes || nodes.length < 1) {
                    console.log("[ers-graph] nodes array is either undefined or empty, graph not rendered.");
                    svg.selectAll("*").remove();
                    return;
                }

                // Create the input graph
                g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph();
                g.setGraph({ nodesep: 20, edgesep: 10, ranksep: 40, rankdir: direction });
                g.setDefaultEdgeLabel(function() { return {}; });

                var labelType;

                // Create nodes
                for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                var label = "";

                if (nodes[i].template) {
                        // var template = Handlebars.compile(nodes[i].template);
                        // label = "<div class='node-content'>" + template(nodes[i].content) + "</div>";
                        // labelType = "html";
                    } else {
                        label = nodes[i].label;
                    }

                    g.setNode(nodes[i].id, {
                        label: label ,
                        shape: nodes[i].shape,
                        labelType: labelType,
                        class: nodes[i].class
                    });
                 };

                // Create edges
                for (var x = 0; x < edges.length; x++) {
                    // Check if the nodes exist for this edge
                    var nodeFrom = nodes.filter(function(item:any) { return item.id === edges[x].from; });
                    var nodeTo = nodes.filter(function(item:any) { return item.id === edges[x].to; });

                    if (edges[x] && nodeFrom.length > 0 && nodeTo.length > 0) {
                        g.setEdge(
                            edges[x].from,
                            edges[x].to,
                            {
                                arrowhead: edges[x].type,
                                label: edges[x].label,
                                // labelpos: 'c', 
                                // labeloffset: 0, 
                                labelStyle: "",
                                lineInterpolate: "basis",
                                style: edges[x].dashed ? "stroke-dasharray: 2, 2;" : ""
                            }
                        );
                    }
                 }

                 if (roundNodeCorners) {
                    g.nodes().forEach(function(v:any) {
                        var node = g.node(v);
                        // Round the corners of the nodes
                        node.rx = 3;
                        node.ry = 3;
                    });
                 }

                //  Create the renderer
                 var render = new dagreD3.render();

                //  Set up an SVG group so that we can translate the final graph.
                 svg.selectAll("*").remove();
                 var svgGroup = svg.append("g");

                // Setup zoom
                zoom = d3.behavior.zoom();

                zoom.on("zoom", function() {
                    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + (<any>d3.event).translate + ")" + "scale(" + (<any>d3.event).scale + ")");
                });

                svg.call(zoom);

                // Enable/disable zoom with mouse wheel
                if (!enableMouseWheelZoom) {
                    svg
                        .on("wheel.zoom", null)
                        .on("mousewheel.zoom", null)
                        .on("DOMMouseScroll.zoom", null);
                }

                // Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
                render(svgGroup, g);

                // Add click events to nodes
                svgGroup.selectAll("g.node").on("click", function(object:any) {
                        nodeSelectedCallback(object);
                });

                //  Add click events to edges
                svgGroup.selectAll("g.edgePath").on("click", function(object:any) {
                        edgeSelectedCallback(object);
                });

                if (selectedNode) {
                    //  Show Selected Node
                    this.showSelectedNode(selectedNode, svg);
                }

                if (selectedEdge) {
                    // Show Selected Edge
                    this.showSelectedEdge(selectedEdge, svg);
                }

                // Add On Node Hover
                svg.selectAll("g.node")
                    .on("mouseover", function(d:any, i:any) {
                        d3.select(this).classed("node-hover", true);
                    })
                    .on("mouseout", function(d:any, i:any) {
                        d3.select(this).classed("node-hover", false);
                    });

                // Add On Edge Hover
                svg.selectAll("g.edgePath")
                    .on("mouseover", function(d:any, i:any) {
                        d3.select(this).classed("edge-hover", true);
                    })
                    .on("mouseout", function(d:any, i:any) {
                        d3.select(this).classed("edge-hover", false);
                    });

                originalZoomScale = zoom.scale();

                this.scaleGraph(svg, isUpdate, autoResizeGraph, direction);

                isUpdate = true;
            };

            this.coordinates = function(point:any) {
                var scale = zoom.scale(), translate = zoom.translate();
                return [(point[0] - translate[0]) / scale, (point[1] - translate[1]) / scale];
            };

            this.point = function(coordinates:any) {
                var scale = zoom.scale(), translate = zoom.translate();
                return [coordinates[0] * scale + translate[0], coordinates[1] * scale + translate[1]];
            };

            this.zoomHelper = function(svg:any, zoomScale:any) {
                svg.call(zoom.event); // https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2387

            //  Record the coordinates (in data space) of the center (in screen space).
                var center0 = zoom.center();
                var translate0 = zoom.translate();
                var coordinates0 = this.coordinates(center0);
                zoom.scale(zoom.scale() * zoomScale);

            //  Translate back to the center.
                var center1 = this.point(coordinates0);
                zoom.translate([translate0[0] + center0[0] - center1[0], translate0[1] + center0[1] - center1[1]]);

                return svg.transition().duration(500).call(zoom.event);
             };
```

**LINK:**

```
       link: function (scope:ng.IScope, elem:ng.IAugmentedJQuery,   attrs:ng.IAttributes, ctrl:any) {
            var direction = ersDiagramService.getDirection(ctrl.direction);
            var element = elem.find("svg")[0];
            var svg = d3.select(element);
            // var translate;

            ersDiagramService.renderGraph(svg, ctrl.nodes, ctrl.edges, ctrl.enableMouseWheelZoom, ctrl.selectedNode,
                ctrl.selectedEdge, function (node:any) {
                    ctrl.onNodeSelectedLocal(node);
            }, function (edge:any){
                    ctrl.onEdgeSelectedLocal(edge);
            }, ctrl.autoResizeGraph);

            scope.$watchCollection("ctrl.nodes", function(newValue:any, oldValue:any) {
                        ersDiagramService.renderGraph(svg, ctrl.nodes, ctrl.edges, ctrl.enableMouseWheelZoom, ctrl.selectedNode,
                        ctrl.selectedEdge, function (node:any) {
                            ctrl.onNodeSelectedLocal(node);
                        }, function (edge:any){
                            ctrl.onEdgeSelectedLocal(edge);
                        }, ctrl.autoResizeGraph);
            });

            scope.$watchCollection("ctrl.edges", function(newValue:any, oldValue:any) {
                    ersDiagramService.renderGraph(svg, ctrl.nodes, ctrl.edges, ctrl.enableMouseWheelZoom, ctrl.selectedNode,
                        ctrl.selectedEdge, function (node:any) {
                            ctrl.onNodeSelectedLocal(node);
                        }, function (edge:any){
                            ctrl.onEdgeSelectedLocal(edge);
                        }, ctrl.autoResizeGraph);
            });

            scope.$watch("ctrl.selectedNode", function() {
                if (ctrl.selectedNode) {
                    ersDiagramService.showSelectedNode(ctrl.selectedNode, svg);
                }
            });

            scope.$watch("ctrl.selectedEdge", function() {
                if (ctrl.selectedEdge) {
                    ersDiagramService.showSelectedEdge(ctrl.selectedEdge, svg);
                }
            });

            elem.find(".btn-zoom-in").bind("click", function() {
                ersDiagramService.zoomHelper(svg, 2);
                return false;
            });

            elem.find(".btn-zoom-out").bind("click", function() {
                ersDiagramService.zoomHelper(svg, 0.5);
                return false;
            });

            elem.find(".btn-actual-size").bind("click", function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ctrl.autoResizeGraph = "disabled";
                });
                ersDiagramService.scaleGraph(svg, true, ctrl.autoResizeGraph, direction);
                return false;
            });

            elem.find(".btn-auto-size").bind("click", function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ctrl.autoResizeGraph = "auto";
                });
                ersDiagramService.scaleGraph(svg, true, ctrl.autoResizeGraph, direction);
                return false;
            });

            elem.find(".btn-fill-view").bind("click", function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ctrl.autoResizeGraph = "fill";
                });
                ersDiagramService.scaleGraph(svg, true, ctrl.autoResizeGraph, direction);
                return false;
            });
      }
    };
```

Help is appreciated!